# Removing checkered background baked onto image

Tags: image-editing, background-removal

I have an image as follows:

[image: checkered background example]

The checkered pattern is not the transparency, it is impressed directly on the image, and runs across the whole graphic.

I would like to know if there is a way to remove the checkered background, extracting the original graphic without (much) damage. I suppose it is impossible, but maybe someone knows a trick.

Comment: Why you can download the voector image [here](https://publicdomainvectors.org/en/free-clipart/Surprise-box-with-a-clown/89223.html). But yeah this has been explained before

Comment: @joojaa this is just an example i made myself to show the problem. I have searched a lot but couldn't find useful links, do you have one?

Comment: Yeah you can solve the mathematical belnding equation. You need to guess the alpha transparency though

Comment: Google does not know your version of the image, except the instance in your GDSE question, but the one with no checkerboard is well known. Is yours the only one? For what actual purpose you expect to extract from here checkerboard removal tricks? Maybe testing the protection method? No method stands redrawing and a competent programmer beats this. I guess.

Comment: @user287001 I created the example above myself from a public domain clipart to make it less boring than just a random shape. I wanted to know this because I have a few personal images that have been saved this way and wanted to know if there was a way to remove the background. Also I was curious about the math involved in solving it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Alpha blending** is:

*C*<sub>out</sub> = *α* * *C*<sub>FG</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BG</sub>

Now there are two alphas on the image: a full transparency and the object transparency. The first order of business is to calculate the full transparency. Because we know the color and structure of the checker, we get a system of equations out of two pixels that have the same color.

*C* = *α* * *C*<sub>FGdark</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BGdark</sub>

*C* = *α* * *C*<sub>FGDLight</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>

In these 2 equations there are 2 unknowns, so first let's solve for alpha. Since C is same in both equations we get:

*α* * *C*<sub>FGdark</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BGdark</sub> = *α* * *C*<sub>FGDLight</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>

And then:

*α* * *C*<sub>FGdark</sub>+  *C*<sub>BGdark</sub> - *α** *C*<sub>BGdark</sub> = *α* * *C*<sub>FGDLight</sub>+*C*<sub>BGLight</sub>
-*α* * *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>

Collect by terms:

*α* * *C*<sub>FGdark</sub> - *α** *C*<sub>BGdark</sub> - *α* * *C*<sub>FGDLight</sub> + *α* * *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>= *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>  -  *C*<sub>BGdark</sub>

break out alpha and divide

*α* = (*C*<sub>BGLight</sub>  -  *C*<sub>BGdark</sub>) /  (*C*<sub>FGdark</sub> - *C*<sub>BGdark</sub> - *C*<sub>FGDLight</sub> +  *C*<sub>BGLight</sub>)

Whew, now that we have calculated the alpha we can go use the first formula and solve it in terms of *C*<sub>BG</sub>:

*C*<sub>out</sub> = *α* * *C*<sub>FG</sub>+(1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BG</sub>

collect by terms and divide:

*C*<sub>FG</sub> = -((1-*α*) * *C*<sub>BG</sub> - *C*<sub>out</sub>)/ *α*

OK let's test this! Take the images:

bg.png and 0.5.png (click to zoom)

[image]
[image]

Where the second is a synthetic check with 50% opacity stroke on the background. We can use ImageMagick to do the calculation. Run the command

```
magick 05.png bg.png -fx "-((0.5)*u[1]-u[0])/0.5" out.png
```

you get out.png

[image: solid stroke on checkered background]

Seems to work rather well. You can now do a difference alpha for an alpha mask.

Now the original image does not seem to be alpha blended. Maybe the mode is multiply or screen? Let us test those next.

**Multiplication mode** is:

*C*<sub>out</sub> = *C*<sub>FG</sub> * *C*<sub>BG</sub>

Thus

*C*<sub>FG</sub> = *C*<sub>out</sub>/*C*<sub>BG</sub>

Testing

[image]
[image]

Results in:

[image]

looks ok. But thats not it either. Maybe multiply with a blend?

**Screen mode** is:

*C*<sub>out</sub> = 1 - (1 - *C*<sub>FG</sub>) * (1 - *C*<sub>BG</sub>)

So:

*C*<sub>FG</sub> = (*C*<sub>BG</sub> - *C*<sub>out</sub>) / (1 - *C*<sub>BG</sub>)

But that wouldnt be recoverable.

OK so not easy. But theres still stuff to go through. Maybe they have multiple alphas? What if the multiplication or blend was done color correctly and not naively like photoshop software tend to do? (Need to do actual work also sorry)

Comment: Interesting. However when you say "apply this to all pixels", you don't mention how to actually achieve that. Could you explain a little?

Comment: @BillyKerr depends heavily on what application you use. I mean in photoshop this is super tedious but for example in a comp app like say nuke, Fusion, Blender or say CAS (computer algebra system) like Mathematica no more work than writing the equation down

Comment: Would it be possible using ImageMagick?

Comment: @BillyKerr maybe i must cogitate a bit how it deals with negative intermediate values.

Comment: Cool, sorry I've got to just now, but if you can come up with anything that would be super amazing!!

Comment: @BillyKerr ok it works but the image in question has a a bit random alpha values. So maybe its not alpha blended maybe its multiplied?

Comment: I was told there would be no math `:)`

Comment: What if the OP's image is a screenshot of an image in CMYK mode?

Comment: If one picks colors from the image he sees easily that in Lab system the checkerboard affects only to L,, a and b are the same in both sides of the border of grey and white background. Thus equalizing the L values with curves would remove the checkerboard. Unfortunately there's also original colors which have difference only in L. In addition the JPG noise and antialiasing blur kill the possibilities to make area selections by color. Otherwise the Quick selection tool would separate easily the differently colored areas. The tool is so clever that it would do it as well without equalizing L

Comment: @user287001 ah, yes i hadnt considered the fact that the checker is above good point.

Comment: @user28701 it shouldnt be impossibly hard to make the checkered pattern though.

Comment: I tried also to fix the image L by inserting a top checkerboard with 1 square offset. I guess you thought the same behind your comment. Unfortunately making it pixel perfect and blending it in a way which globally equalizes adjacent L values of the otherwise same color are both  still unsolved if one wants to use Photoshop or other image editor via its GUI.

Comment: Check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MadsWolff/eoxtnp29/) I made. It's a script where you upload a background image and a blended image, the script finds the used alpha and returns an unblended image. The method is explained in comments.

Comment: This is really impressive have to say! But it seems like it still requires at least the original background in order to remove it properly, otherwise completely removing the background non destructively is impossible. Still, this is more than I expected to be possible! Thanks for the throughout answer.

Comment: Also the blending I used for the example is just normal alpha blending with the checkered pattern on the background

Comment: @Andrea, the checkered background in your example can easily be recreated. But your example [fails in my script](https://i.imgur.com/8CTmTe3.png). Are parts of the illustration already semi-transparent? The method only works perfectly if all pixels of the foreground image have the same alpha. So for images with transparent background, the background image can't be removed. Like in joojaa's example, where the checkers remain.

Comment: @Wolff its probably because there is a space transform between this and that. Probably worth testing this with srgb to linear and back.